# Mysterious file I can't remove

Tags: linux

```
root@host [/home2/newgames/public_html/hello/cache/javascripttostring.com]# rm -rf *
root@host [/home2/newgames/public_html/hello/cache/javascripttostring.com]# ls
/bin/ls: cannot access http\260\353\232\366\354\a: No such file or directory
./  ../  http\260\353\232\366\354\a
root@host [/home2/newgames/public_html/hello/cache/javascripttostring.com]#
```

What should I do?

rm -rf * doesn't work. There is this one magical file that is in limbo. Between existing and non existing. The hard drive were once full

Comment: it's seems that file is created again by some process, could you please post output of `ls -lrti` before delete and after delete ?

Comment: Additionally run the command find . -exec lsof {} \; which should show you the process which is potentially opening that file.

Comment: You should probably run a filesystem check. (Sooner rather than later too.)

Comment: Looks like it's a wayward file in a failing SSD

Comment: Have you tried to use the command `file` to figure out what it is?

Comment: `rm -f` hides errors on delete.  What happens without the `-f`?  It's also possible to check for failures with `strace`.  BTW - a once-full harddrive shouldn't cause problems, although an `fsck` (file system check) could be helpful.

Comment: By the way - the odd-looking filename is actually valid, and does not contain backslashes - the `\260` is the octal value of the character at that place in the file.  With that said, the `rm` command should be able to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a file that both exists and doesn't exist. This means the filesystem is damaged.

First, [run a memory test](http://www.memtest.org/). Faulty RAM can cause filesystem corruption, and the longer you work with faulty memory, the more corrupted your data will become. Let the test run for at least one full pass. If it reports errors, turn off your computer, change the RAM, and restore your data from backups.

From this point I assume that your RAM is in perfect working order.

If this is not your root filesystem, unmount it. If this is your root filesystem, boot from a rescue system such as [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/). Then run `fsck` on the damaged filesystem.

Check your system logs to see if there have been disk failures. If a disk is failing, replace it immediately.

Filesystem corruption should not happen with working hardware unless you use avant-garde software that isn't ready for prime time.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command:

```
$ find . -delete
```

This will enumerate the various files and directories under the current path and then delete them.

Comment: How would this differ from `rm`?

Comment: @sparhawk It's a matter of input.  In the case of `rm` one may only reference the file by it's name.  The name is not the _file_ though, only metadata about the file.  In the case of `find` it is traversing the directory structure and for each inode referenced under that structure complying with some number of filters may have an action taken on them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The name supplied to `rm` is just a pointer to the inode. And in your example, there are no "filters" supplied to `find`, so that point is moot.

Comment: The original question is asking how to remove all of the content within a specific directory, which is failing.  When you run rm -rf * it's actually performing file globbing via the "*".  Globbing is not happening behind the scenes when using find (at least in the same problematic way).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but in what situation would the latter work and the former fail?